# Calculate the converging limit of this series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

$$
\left\{
\begin{split}
S(0)   &=    1\\
S(i+1)  &=   \left(1+\frac{1}{2i} \right) S(i)\qquad  \text{for}~  i > 0
\end{split}
\right.
$$
I somehow figured out that this series must converge, but could not find the value where it converges.

Comment: What is $\frac{1}{2i}$ for i = 0?

Comment: After edit - what is S(1) then :-) ?

Comment: I think it actually doesn't converge ... (just by looking at the numbers)

Comment: it's not yet properly defined, how it can converge or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean $S(1) = 1$ - otherwise your sequence is still not well defined - the sequence does not converge:

- Set $l_i := \ln S(i)$ for $i \in \mathbb{N}$
- $\Rightarrow l_{i+1} = \ln(2i+1) - \ln (2i) + l_i$ and $l_1 =0$
- $\Rightarrow l_{i+1} = l_1 + \sum_{k=1}^i(l_{i+1} - l_i) = \sum_{k=1}^i(\ln(2i+1) - \ln (2i))$
- The [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) gives $\ln(2i+1) - \ln (2i)> \frac{1}{2i+1}$

$$\Rightarrow l_{i+1} > \sum_{k=1}^i\frac{1}{2i+1}> \sum_{k=1}^i\frac{1}{2i+2}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^i\frac{1}{i+1}\stackrel{i \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} \infty$$

Hence,

$$S(i) = e^{l_i} \stackrel{i \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} \infty$$

Answer (score 2):

If it was $$\left\{
\begin{split}
S_1   &=    1\\
S_{i+1}  &=   \left(1+\frac{1}{2i} \right) S_i\qquad  \text{for}~  i > 1
\end{split}
\right.$$
using Pochhammer symbols, the result would be
$$S_i=\frac{\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)_{i-1}}{(1)_{i-1}}$$ Expanded as series for large values of $i$ we should have
$$S_i=\frac{2 \sqrt{i}}{\sqrt{\pi }}-\frac{1}{4 \sqrt{\pi i
   }}+\frac{1}{64 \sqrt{\pi i^3
   }}+O\left(\frac{1}{i^2}\right)$$ which does not converge.

Trying for $i=10$, the exact result is 
$$S_{10}=\frac{230945}{65536}\approx 3.52394$$ while the above truncated series would give $\frac{12641}{640 \sqrt{10 \pi }}\approx 3.52392$